# Text inside button placed anormally

Tags: html, css, ejs

I'm currently making a to-do list. The problem that I have is after applying basic css, the + text inside the button is a little bit upward. I couldn't understand why it is and I want to apply margin-top but how can I specifically apply it to the text inside the button?

Image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYDEt.jpg)
Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Kworth To Do List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="box" id="heading">
    <h1> <%= kindOfDay %> </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <% for (i = 0; i < newListItem.length; i++) { %>
    <div class="item">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <p> <%= newListItem[i] %> </p>
    </div>
    <% }; %>
    <form class="item" action="/" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New Item" autocomplete="off">
      <button type="submit" name="button" class="test">+</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <ul>


  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Css:

```
html {
  background-color: #E4E9FD;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(65deg, #A683E3 50%, #E4E9FD 50%);
  min-height: 1000px;
  font-family: 'helvetica neue';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#heading {
  background-color: #A683E3;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  min-height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
}

.item:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

input:checked+p {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  text-decoration-color: #A683E3;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin: 20px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #00204a;
}

form {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

button {
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: #A683E3;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  border-width: 0;
}

input[type="text"] {
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  top: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
  width: 313px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 0 #A683E3;
}

::placeholder {
  color: grey;
  opacity: 1;
}

footer {
  color: white;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `padding-bottom: 6px` from button.

```css
html {
  background-color: #E4E9FD;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(65deg, #A683E3 50%, #E4E9FD 50%);
  min-height: 1000px;
  font-family: 'helvetica neue';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#heading {
  background-color: #A683E3;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  min-height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
}

.item:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

input:checked+p {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  text-decoration-color: #A683E3;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin: 20px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #00204a;
}

form {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

button {
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: #A683E3;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  /*padding-bottom: 6px;*/ /* REMOVE THIS */
  border-width: 0;
}

input[type="text"] {
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  top: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
  width: 313px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 0 #A683E3;
}

::placeholder {
  color: grey;
  opacity: 1;
}

footer {
  color: white;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="box" id="heading">
    <h1> <%= kindOfDay %> </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <% for (i = 0; i < newListItem.length; i++) { %>
    <div class="item">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <p> <%= newListItem[i] %> </p>
    </div>
    <% }; %>
    <form class="item" action="/" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New Item" autocomplete="off">
      <button type="submit" name="button" class="test">+</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <ul>


  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to specify `line-height` to be the same as the `height`, which is 50px in your case.

Also why you have `top` property in `input[type="text"]` when it would only work if you have `position` property set as `relative` or `absolute`.